# Distance between Polar Coordinates

Tags: java

How do you find the distance between PolarCoordinates with angle and radius.
I know that the formula is:

`d = sqrt(r1^2 + r2^2 -2r1r2cos(theta2 - theta1)`

How do you write it when the coordinates are just angle and radius

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: No like one of the questions was to write a 
public double distanceFrom() function using polar coordinates but how do I implement radius 1 and 2 into that ??

Comment: @swagstar123 unclear what are u asking

Comment: the main function takes angle and radius as the two inputs
My question is how do I do r2 and r1 and theta2 and theta1
when I have one radius and one angle 
how do I divide radius into r1 and r2

Comment: @swagstar123 u should have all r1,r2 and theta1 ,theta2 then u can find distance according to that equation.if u have only r1and theta 1 then data is insufficient.but why ur function take only 2 arguments take 4 .
`public double distanceFrom(double r1,double theata1,double r2,double theta2){}`

Comment: my main function is , PolarPoint(double angle, double radius)
and this function is public double distanceFrom(Point other).
How would I implement it here. Thanks for your help

Comment: @swagstar123 why 2 functions still unclear

Comment: No the PolarPoint is the class and the DistanceFrom is a function under that. Thanks for your help

Comment: What you mean is that you have a constructor `PolarPoint(double angle, double radius)` in your `PolarPoint` class.  If your `distanceFrom` method is in the `PolarPoint` class, then it has access to the private fields of that class.  That means, you can write things like `other.angle` and `other.radius` inside that method; which is what you'll need to do here, assuming that those are the correct names of your fields.

Comment: If r1 is other.radius what would r2 be ?
Sorry for asking a lot of questions, just trying to understand the concepts

Comment: Please I need help ASAP

Answer (score 2):

Please read up on classes - you need a class PolarPoint that has a method distanceFrom - tested:

```
class PolarPoint {

    private double angle;
    private double radius;

    public PolarPoint(double angle, double radius) {
        this.angle = angle;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double distanceFrom(PolarPoint other){
         double theta1 = this.angle;
         double theta2 = other.angle;
         double r1 = this.radius;
         double r2 = other.radius;
         return Math.sqrt(r1*r1 + r2*r2 - 2*r1*r2*Math.cos(theta2 - theta1));
   }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        PolarPoint p1 = new PolarPoint(0, 0); // the origin
        PolarPoint p2 = new PolarPoint(Math.PI, 1); // (-1, 0)
        System.out.println(p1.distanceFrom(p2));
    }
}
```

As a side note - angle and radius should be made final, to make this immutable. But I guess from the comments (namely rotate()) that this is a mutable Point - yak!

Comment: I get this error. PolarPoint.java:52: error: possible loss of precision
        int  theta1 = this.angle;

Comment: Where in my code did you see ___int___ theta1 ?

Comment: no first I didnt have the int and then it said cannot find symbol, so I changed it and tried

Comment: PolarPoint.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
          theta1 = this.angle;
          ^
  symbol:   variable theta1
  location: class PolarPoint
PolarPoint.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
          theta2 = other.angle;

Comment: It's telling you that you have a double you are trying to squeeze into an int variable - error - well look at my edited code - it runs out of the box - but you really should start reading ;)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again.
but I still get this error.
PolarPoint.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
         double theta2 = other.angle;
I dont get the error for this.angle.

Comment: The code above runs: https://ideone.com/rcmNsN - look _carefully_ at what you have. _Use an IDE like eclipse - do not edit your code in notepad. Format your code and do not leave uneeded blank lines_ - this can be done automatically in eclipse

Comment: This is the code I have

    public double distanceFrom(Point other)
    {
         double  theta1 = this.angle;
         double theta2 = other.angle;
         double r1 = this.radius;
         double r2 = other.radius;
         return sqrt(r1*r1 + r2*r2 -2*r1*r2*Math.cos(theta2 - theta1)); 
    }

Comment: This is my whole code for the function. https://ideone.com/SDUvz9

Comment: Indent this correctly, give me Point definition, make it compile on ideone and let _no extra blank lines_

Comment: Point definition. public interface Point
{
double xCoordinate();
double yCoordinate();
double radius();
double angle();
double distanceFrom(Point other);
Point rotate90();
}

Comment: proper indentation and spaces
https://ideone.com/VyC5bJ

Comment: Still you had error in indentation but it looked better - please _put the brace in the same line as the method_ - this is no C - will save you _a lot_ of space. Compiles (but lacks main) https://ideone.com/MiLKZW

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Thank you so much 
Is there a way that you might be able to fix the rotate90 method 
Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Also I get this.  error: PolarPoint is not abstract and does not override abstract method distanceFrom(Point) in Point

Comment: Yeah - please do your homework - last try : same link. I don't know what's in Point

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
class PolarPoint {
    private double innerRadius;
    private double innerAngle;
    public PolarPoint(double radius,double angle) {
        innerRadius = radius;
        innerAngle = angle;
    }
    public double getRadius() {
        return innerRadius;
    }
    public double getAngle() {
        return innerAngle;
    }
   public double polarDistance(PolarPoint otherPoint) {
        return Math.sqrt(innerRadius*innerRadius + otherPoint.getRadius()*otherPoint.getRadius() -2*innerRadius*otherPoint.getRadius()*Math.cos(innerAngle-otherPoint.getAngle()));
    }
}
```

The polarDistance method at the end gives the distance between the PolarPoint object and another PolarPoint. Note that the angle theta must be in Radians.

Comment: Actually the distancFrom function only takes one argument which is otherPoint. Thats why I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public double PolarDistance(double r1,double theta1,double r2,double theta2) {
    return Math.sqrt(r1*r1 + r2*r2 -2*r1*r2*Math.cos(theta2 - theta1));
}
```

This should work. r1 and theta1 are the coordinates of the first point and r2 and theta 2 are the coordinates of the second point.

Comment: public class PolarPoint(double radius, double angle)
public double distanceFrom(Point other).

This is given. How do I implement distancefrom using just angle and radius? Thanks for your help